# ruby gem dependency issue, need to know if a gem is compatible before running bundle install?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, dependencies

I'm setting up the GemFile following some tutorial.
If an older version of a gem specifies its dependency as rake ~>10.3 on rubygems.org
does that mean a later version of rake won't work with this gem?

Comment: Well most of these gems don't have backward compatibility, you might need to update your code if you change the version of the gems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rake ~>10.3` means: `10.3.0 <= version < 11.0.0`. The dependency constraint is *not* saying that `rake` must be exactly version `10.3.0`.

The only thing I can say with certainty is that the bundle will refuse to install unless it contains a version of `rake` in that range.

Would the gem *actually* work with a later version of `rake`? Maybe. It depends what the code actually does! The old version of this gem was probably (?) written before `rake v11.0.0` was released, therefore there was no way of knowing, at the time, whether or not it would be compatible.

You *could*  create your own copy of the old gem version and try loosening/removing the dependency constraint, but I wouldn't recommend it; it's best to just upgrade all code to use newer (ideally the latest) versions, or downgrade other libraries for compatibility if absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Gem dependency is a case-by-case basis. There is no possible way to say that any gem will or won't be backwards compatible, you have to test. The "closer" the version is, the more likely it is to be compatible, but this is in no way a rule that you can go by or trust.

In addition, I don't know if you are understanding the syntax of that either. `~> 10.3` does not mean that rake must be version `10.3`. It is a slightly confusing operand, but limits the version to a subset of versions.

Comment: Actually it is not too confusing. The squiggly arrow operator `~>` allows the last specified versioning level to be at least the given one and everything above but forbids more relevant levels to rise.
So `~> 5.2` means "at least `5.2`, and `5.x` with `x > 2` is ok too - but don't give me `6.0` or anything above though". Likewise `~> 5.2.3` means `5.2.x` with `x >= 3` - but everything above `5.3` will be disallowed.

Comment: Yeah, confusing to know all that if you never seen it before and just see a squiggly arrow pointing to a gem version number...